# Where are variables? Where is their value?

Tags: c++, c

I know a variable is a storage location paired with an associated symbolic name, now I write down this

```
int a=8;
```

My questions are:

Where is `8`? Is the address of `8` same with the address of `a`?

Comment: `8` is an integer literal and `a` is an variable.

Comment: Thank you! But  I what to know where a is in memory and 8 in memory。

Comment: It may go into code or data section and may be used for the initialization.

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11965675/1771055

Comment: Sorry for the self-plug, but this might clarify things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247824/when-changing-the-value-of-a-variable-in-c-is-a-new-primitive-created-or-is-the/29248076#29248076. It also goes over a simple pointer example.

Comment: As for the 8, it would usually be an operand to an instruction that stores the value 8 into the location where `a` is stored, if the declaration is within a function. If the declaration is global, then the 8 would be part of the initialized data segment, which is loaded as part of your program when the operating system starts it.

Comment: @Ulfalizer  Can I know where is 8?now I know where is a,but I don't know where is 8.I know it will in code section or data section,I want the Accurate address.

Comment: @zentionshon: If it's in the data section, then the location is just the address of `a`. If it's in the code section (as the operand of an instruction that stores the value 8 into `a`), then there's nothing built-in in C to get the address. You could look at a disassembly for example.

Comment: If you can't afford one, a pro-deo [tag:language-lawyer] will probably be assigned to you

Comment: [Here's another explanation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/245665/understanding-how-variable-assignment-works/246800#246800).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare the variable int a and set it to 8, your computer will actually reserve a place in your memory where it put's the 8. You can derive the actual location (memory address) by assigning the adress to another variable like this:

```
int* b = &a;
```

This will assign the adress where a (the 8) is stored to a new variable b.

If you're using Visual-Studio which assume by your tag visual c++ you can also use the on board utilities to make this visible. Open the Register, Assembly and Debug Views

- Debug -> Windows -> Registers
- Debug -> Windows -> Dissassembly
- Debug -> Windows -> Memory -> Memory1.

By stepping through your calls in the dissassembly view you can actually see what happens in memory.

I used a slightly extended example of your codeline to force to show Visual Studio to show the interesting happenings:

```
int a = 8;

//increment the value in a by 1 and assign it to 1
a = a + 1;

//Get the memory address where the 8 has been 
//stored and set it to b
int* b = &a;
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, very nice answer!
I had known what on earth my question means since I learnd a little 8086 asm.

Answer (score 9):

Variables are named location in memory. In other words, variables are just a place holder for a value. When you declare

```
int a = 8;
```

`8` is stored at the memory location named as `a`. This integer literal can be accessed from that memory location using `a`.

```
    0x12345        <--- Memory address            
+-------------+
|             |
|      8      |
|             |
+-------------+
       a           <--- Name used to access value stored at location 0x12345
```

You can think of it as putting the value assigned in a box with the variable name.

```
int a = 1;
```

[image]

Comment: I only know computer is full of 0 and 1.so the a must has a address to store.so does 8.

Comment: @zentionshon 8 is a value. You can store an 8 in a location, but the number 8 doesn't have a location.

Comment: You can store an 8 in a location, but the number 8 doesn't have a location?why?I am more confused.

Comment: @zentionshon; Number `8` is stored at some location. It doesn't have a location because it is not a variable.

Comment: Gotta love the box example image.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is a *definition* and *initialization* of variable `a`. If we break down the process in simple terms, it looks like

```
int a=8;
```

- declares a variable named `a` of type `int`
- defines it (allocates memory)
- initalizes the variable with a value `8`. [FWIW, here `8` is `int` literal]

There is no seperate `8` present after this. `a` holds the value `8`, that's all.

Comment: How does the program know to initialize the variable with the value 8? That 8 has to be written somewhere (ROM in micro-controllers for instance).

Comment: I have the same question with @rozina ,advanced programmers doesn't see our thinking。

Comment: @rozina The code that initialises the variable is an instruction that says "store the number 8 in location xxxx".

Comment: @molbdnilo Which means the number 8 is stored in the instruction, so the code section. That might answer zeniton's question.

Comment: @rozina untill initialization, the _int literal_ 8 is present as a prt of the _instruction_, after execution of `int a = 8;` the _int literal_ 8 is not there anymore _to be accessed_. The variable `a` _has_ the value of `8`. Depending on the storage type of `a`, the instruction to initialize `a` containing the value `8` can be present in different sections of the executable.

Comment: @SouravGhosh What do you mean "it is not there anymore"? Instructions don't get erased out of the executable. It is there forever as part of the instruction that creates the variable a. It does not have a memory address though, so you can not read it.

Comment: @rozina I meant visibility or accessibilty, just the same you meant in the last part of your comment.

Comment: You're actually wrong. This is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). Firstly 8 is created in memory, then it is called `a` (`a` takes the posession of the memory address of 8).

Answer (score 2):

**In binary executable file space**

When you say `int a=8;` in global scope, `8` may go into **data section** which would be later used to initlaize `a` while loading the executable.

When you say `int a=8;` in local scope, `8` may go into **code section** which would be later used to initlaize variable `a` (which may lie in stack segment of process<sup>`*`</sup>) when program flow reaches this line of code.

For more details you can study how binary executables(ELF for example) are packed and about different sections.

**In process space**

There is nothing like literal or `8`, variable `a` has an address and `8` is stored at that address. This is the reason you can not take address of literals. (`&8` for example is wrong because it does not have an address, it is stored at some location anonymously or with a variable alias which can be addressed)

<sup>`*` Assuming implementation uses stack for local variables which is true for all the implementations I have ever seen.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! You mean that a and 8 is store different place in memory?And 8 is in data section or code setion?where is "a" store?

Comment: @zentionshon `8` is stored in binary. `a` may or may not be stored literally after compilation. It is stored if it has external binding otherwise it is resolved during compilation. And the resolved address offset when added with run time base is the address that we actually see (printing with `%p`). But the name `a` itself is stripped off after compilation or linking (internal/external linking) unless you need it for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is the name of a location.
`8` is the value that should be stored in that location.

The code that is generated from `int a = 8` is usually an instruction that says "store the number 8 in location xxxx", where "xxxx" is the location chosen for `a`'s storage.
So the `8` would normally be stored in the code and copied to the place where it's supposed to be used.

(There have been platforms that didn't do it this way, and actually copied small numbers from specific memory locations. In that case, you could say that the number has a location, but that was a very long time ago.)

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a variable. When your program is run it is in the computer's RAM/memory and has an address just as every value in the RAM has an address.

When your program runs, `8` is *copied* to `a`, and hence to where `a` is located in the computer's RAM (its memory address). The memory location pointed out by the address of `a` now contains the *value* of `8`.

Now when your program is run, the name of the variable doesn't matter anymore. It has been transformed by the compiler to point to some relative memory location. And so in runtime we talk with addresses, though we (humans, not computers) save brain power by using the variable name to represent that location on the memory (the address).

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to look at the low level details for some consecutive variables.

```
int a = 8;
char b[4] = "ABC";
int c = 4;
```

`a` is a variable. As such it has a location in memory say `0x1012`. Assuming no unexpected optimisation moved anything here is how memory will be organized for a little endian 32 bit system

```
0x1012  8   // lowest byte of a
0x1013  0
0x1014  0
0x1015  0   // highest byte of a
0x1016  65  // (or 0x41 ) ASCII for A first byte of b array
0x1017  66
0x1018  67
0x1019  0   // terminating null
0x101A  4   // lowest byte for c
0x101B  0
0x101C  0
0x101D  0   // highest byte for c
```

You can see here how a, b, and c which are variable have addresses in memory, and why 8, 4 and "abc" are values residing in variable.

If later you have `a=20`, memory will change that way :

```
0x1012  4   // lowest byte of a
0x1013  1
0x1014  0   // remaining unchanged ...
```

Here again 20 has no location